# Force browser to open DOCX files in full word not Word plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web

I have a web application which lists DOCX files within a directory when the users click a link the document opens within the browser using the word plug in. Is it at all possible to force the browser to open the document in full word instead of the word plug in?

This application is running on a corporate network and i have no access to amend any settings on the machines it can only be done from the web server.

They are currently using IE6 and a browser upgrade is not due for several months.

I suspect the answer is it cant be done.

Comment: Do you have a link to the plugin that is causing the issues?  There are many different preview plugins out there so getting around all of them could prove very hard.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I achieve a solution using a `Generic Handler`.

Add a new `GeneriChandler.cs` to you project and in the `ProcessRequest` do this code:

```
//Search for the file by querystring or other method you did, like name.
string fileId = context.Request.QueryString["fileId"];
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\" + fileId + ".docx");                
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
context.Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
```

So if your handler is called `MyHandler.ashx` you can call the file in the link like that :

```
<a href="MyHandler.ashx?fileId=1">File 1</a>
```

Comment: I'm surprised the OP didn't even acknowledge the answer. :/